# Magento does not recognize new module

Tags: magento-1.7

i tried like all tutorials out there and i still cannot get a custom created module to work in Magento.

This is the path where i created the XML file on the server to tell Magento what the module is:

app/etc/modules/Multiplies_HelloWorld.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
    <modules>
       <Multiplies_HelloWorld>
          <active>true</active>
          <codePool>local</codePool>
       </Multiplies_HelloWorld>
    </modules>
 </config>
```

This is the module path:

app/code/local/Multiplies/HelloWorld/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config> 
   <modules>
     <Multiplies_HelloWorld>
       <version>0.0.1</version>
     </Multiplies_HelloWorld>
   </modules>
</config>
```

when i go to System/Configuration/Advanced i see a whole bunch of other modules except mine.

I tried to flush the cash, disable it, clear it manualy, restart browser, relog but still no module in my list.

The version im using is magento 1.7.0.2 (free)

Im using FileZilla to upload files.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is the missing `etc` in your `config.xml` path just a typo? The file needs to be in the `etc` subfolder to work.

Comment: thats a typo, i changed it, thanks.

Comment: Have you already compared owner, group and permissions of your FTP uploaded files with other working module files (i.e. which are correctly shown in System -> Configuration -> Advanced)?

Comment: Other than that, have you checked that your `app/etc/local.xml` has a `<disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>` line?

Comment: Yes to both. Other modules with same permission/group show up, same as the rule in local.xml.

Comment: I successfully tested your two files on a naked 1.7.0.2 a few minutes ago. So it's definitely not an issue with the file contents. Please doublecheck that the paths of your files are correct (files in the right folder, upper-/lowercasing of the file names exactly as you posted). In case you created multiple test modules doublecheck that your modules handle `<Multiplies_HelloWorld>` does not accidentally exist twice (e.g. in one of your other test modules).

Comment: Thanks for your input so far. I realy checked 10 times if my names/directories are correct and they are....I cant implement anything without the possiblity to add custom made modules.

Comment: Same issue with 1.9 . Flush magento cache (Admin Panel > System > Cache Management > Flush Magento Cache ) or disable cache   for development (Admin Panel > System > Cache Management > Select All > Actions: Disable > Submit ) solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit late, but I was just having this same problem.

After 20 minutes of chin scratching I tried resetting all caches (System > Cache Management) and then it popped up!

I'm disabling the "configuration" cache while heavily developing a module. I think that'll help reduce friction.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your `etc/module.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="OrgName_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

2. Make sure your `composer.json` has this:

```
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "OrgName\\ModuleName\\": ""
    }
  }
```

3. Make sure your `registration.php` looks like this:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'OrgName_ModuleName',
    isset($file) && realpath($file) == __FILE__ ? dirname($file) : __DIR__
);
```

4. If your module is contained in a symlinked directory that is outside of magento root directory (happens when you use local `"path":` as a module's repository description in composer), you have to allow magento for symlinks with: `bin/magento config:set dev/template/allow_symlink 1` . See https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/315525/88882 for more info.